# Google play_billing project disappearing

Tags: android, eclipse, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to follow the Android tutorial on in-app billing found here - http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#AddToDevConsole

It asks me to import the play_billing project into Eclipse from the SDK/extras/Google/play_billing folder which I did the same way I've imported in many other projects. However it doesn't appear on the left-hand side along with my other projects. It won't let me re-import it as it says it's there, but I'm not seeing it.

I've tried re-starting Eclipse and cleaning all projects but no luck. Any idea where it's hiding or how to get the project to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have this project in your Eclipse workspace already (a), or it was added to another working set (b).

a) To fix this issue you need to delete project from Eclipse Workspace. Open Workspace folder, find project there and delete it. Afterwards you can import project again. To find out Workspace folder open *File* - *Switch Workspace*. You will see workspace folder there.

b) Press small triangle button in the *Project Explorer* (see picture) and choose *Edit Active Working Set* option. Find your project and add it to working set content.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right now Edit Active Working Set is grayed out - any idea what I need to do to edit that? Eclipse seems to think it's in the workspace, but I can't for the life of me find it anywhere. It's not under the Open Workspace folder on the left - it should be pretty easy to find there as it starts with T as well so should be at the bottom.

Comment: If it is grayed out, then option b) is not your case. You have project in workspace already. Remove it from there and you will be able to import.